# How to check email overlap using Axios get and post for SignUp with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to filter overlap validation for SignUp email.

in my api.js

```
  const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'));

  const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: baseURL, // already set our base URL

  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  }
});
```

and in my authService.js

```
const register = (countryCode, name, email, password) => {
  return axios
    .post('/auth/signup', {
      countryCode,
      name,
      email,
      password,
    })
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.headers.authorization) {
        console.log(response);
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.headers.authorization));
      }
      return response.headers.authorization;
    });
};
```

```
const login = (email, password) => {
  api
    .post('/auth/signin', {
      email,
      password,
    })
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.headers.authorization) {
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.headers.authorization));
      }
      return response.data;
    });
};
```

```
const checkEmail = (email) => {
  return api.get('/public/email', { email }).then((response) => {
    if (response.data.exist === true) {
      return localStorage.getItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.data));
    }
    return response.data;
  });
};
```

This checkEmail will be in the SignUp.js

for onChange={emailChange}

```
const onChangeEmail = (e) => {
    const email = e.target.value;
    if (!email.includes('@')) {
      setEmailError('Invalid email');
    } else if (email.includes('@')) {
      setEmailError(null);
    }

    AuthService.checkEmail(email).then(
      (response) => setEmailError('Already Registered Email'),
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );

    setEmail(email);
  };
```

after this code,

in the console
it error

```
Error: Request failed with status code 401
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)
```

I think inn the api.get(URl, {something})

that {something} is wrong but I don't have any idea for hours...

what can I do for this error??

Comment: Sorry in the authService all axios change to api

Answer (score 0):

you can't send body parameter in GET , for that POST,PUT will work,
to send with GET then attach data to the GET url.

example
if your using node server at backend then

```
      api.get('/public/email/'+email).then((resp)=>{
           log(resp);
  }
```

collect the data using

```
router.get("public/email/:youremail",(req,res)=>{
        req.param.youremail
   }
```